# Overload resolution issue in generic vector class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, generics, lambda

I have a generic vector class in which I've implemented a constructor that accepts a functor. The idea being that the functor is called to initialise each element in the vector, the functor's single parameter being the element index.

However this is interfering with my "from scalar" constructor when passing a scalar of a different type than the vector's element type:

```
template <typename T, int N>
struct SomeVectorClass
{
    T values[N];

    SomeVectorClass() {}

    SomeVectorClass(T scalar)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) values[i] = scalar;
    }

    template <typename InitFunctionType>
    SomeVectorClass(InitFunctionType initFunction)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) values[i] = initFunction(i);
    }
};

...

SomeVectorClass<int, 2> a([&] (int i) { return i; }); // This works
SomeVectorClass<int, 2> b(123); // This works
SomeVectorClass<int, 2> c(123.f); // This causes error "called object type 'float' is not a function or function pointer"
```

What I was expecting for `c` was for the compiler to automatically cast `123.f` to `123` and then call the "from scalar" constructor (which accepts an `int` in this case).

Three questions:

1. Is the lambda constructor preferred by the overload resolution because it doesn't require casting?
2. Is there a way to make this work without `std::enable_if` or similar hacks?
3. If not, how would I use `std::enable_if` to only enable the functor constructor if `InitFunctionType` is a functor?

Thanks in advance for your time!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that I can't use `std::function`, for performance reasons. The class needs to be inline-friendly.

Comment: `template <typename InitFunctionType, typename = typename std::result_of<InitFunctionType&(int)>::type> SomeVectorClass(InitFunctionType initFunction)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor template is preferred because it is an Exact Match, while the `T` constructor requires a Conversion. Exact Match is preferred.

This is exactly the kind of problem that  `enable_if` exists to solve. You need to remove the constructor template from the overload resolution set unless it's actually callable with a `int`:

```
template <typename F,
          typename = typename std::result_of <F(int)>::type>
SomeVectorClass (F func) { }
```

That way, constructing with a `float` or `char` will pick your `T` constructor. It's the only candidate!

**Note**: `std::result_of` is not necessarily SFINAE friendly ([N3462](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3462.html)). The above will work on gcc 4.9.2 but not on gcc 4.7.2. If the above fails to compile, with something like

> include/c++/4.7.2/type_traits:1834:9: error: ‘`std::declval<float>()`’ cannot be used as a function

Then you can rewrite the "functor" construtor as:

```
template <typename F,
          typename = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<int>()))
SomeVectorClass (F func) { }
```

Comment: This... seems to good to be true. X-D Seems to work though. No caveats or anything?

Comment: @JonnyBoy Nope. Note that `F` doesn't even have to take specifically an `int`... you can construct with something like `[](double d){return d;}` too. Just as long as it's callable with an `int`.

Comment: Isn't that rather fragile? I thought `result_of` wasn't required to be SFINAE-friendly in the beginning and also wasn't on some compilers.

Comment: @pmr Yep, updated with link to open-std paper and an actual SFINAE-friendly solution.

Comment: Barry & @pmr, thanks for the SFINAE update guys, but std::result_of() seems to work using my current compiler at least, which is the latest Apple-flavoured LLVM. Is it accidental/erroneous that it compiles?
EDIT: clang version is "Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.49) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++11 wall of code containing a bunch of C++14 features that your compiler might not have, plus some useful metaprogramming machinery:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;}; // hold tags
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type; // get types from tags
template<class...>struct voider:tag<void>{}; // everything goes to void

template<class...Ts>using void_t=type_t<voider<Ts...>>; // nothing is

template<class...>struct types{using type=types;}; // bundle of types

namespace details {
  // SFINAE friendly result_of:
  template<class Sig, class=void>
  struct invoke;
  template<class F, class...Args>
  struct invoke<F(Args...),
    void_t< decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)) >
  >:tag< decltype( std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...)) > {};
};
// C++14 style type alias for the above:
template<class Sig>
using invoke_t = type_t<details::invoke<Sig>>;

namespace details {
  // can apply takes a template and some types
  // and is true iff applying the types to the template is valid:
  template<template<class...>class Z, class types, class=void>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, types<Ts...>, void_t<Z<Ts...>>>:
    std::true_type
  {};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply=details::can_apply<Z,types<Ts...>>;

// together, this gives us a "can we invoke a signature"
// in one line:
template<class Sig>
using can_invoke=can_apply< invoke_t, Sig >;

// C++14 feature, want it in C++11:
template<bool b, class X=void>
using enable_if_t=type_t<std::enable_if<b,X>>
```

Now, with the above, the problem is simple:

```
template<class F, class=enable_if_t< can_invoke<F&(int)>::value >>
SomeVectorClass(F&& initFunction)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      values[i] = initFunction(i);
}
```

and easy to read.  Always try to hide nasty `decltype` stuff in utility headers, don't mix it with end-user code.